# In-App Purchase Swift

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am using IAPHelper to implement in-app purchase, an error is occurring when I go to another view controller after pressing the purchase button. For instance, when I press the purchase button then go to another view controller the error is presented after finishing the purchase work.

```
class selectQuestion_ViewController:  UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

let helper = IAPHelper(productIdentifiers: NSSet(object: "sppid") as Set<NSObject>)
 func purchase(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        startLoading("Purchasing ..")
        self.helper.requestProductsWithCompletionHandler({ (success, products) -> Void in

            if success {
                self.endLoading()
                println("wohooooo")
                var sdad =  self.helper.productsDict["sppid"]
                self.helper.buyProduct(sdad!)

            } else {
                self.endLoading()
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Cannot retrieve products list right now.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }


        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you do not use such modules. It would be much better for you and your understanding of IAPs that you check this tutorial and implement the code and methods described there: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1gQklbrgjc

Once you have implemented that code, if something doesn't work (you may have forgotten a line somewhere), come back to SO and we will gladly help you out. Already, as quick help, here is an answer that could help you with most errors once you implement your IAP code with something else than IAP helper: [My IAP isn't working. Bugs at func Paymentqueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741619/my-iap-isnt-working-bugs-at-func-paymentqueue)

In fact, you can watch the video and copy paste the code of my question. My IAP code works ;) Will save you time. But watch the video to understand how to implement IAPs !

I hope this answer helped you ;)

Here is the full IAP code :

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit


class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate,GADBannerViewDelegate{


    @IBOutlet var outRemoveAds: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var outRestorePurchases: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("val") != nil {
            print("Has a value.")
            banner.removeFromSuperview()
            bannerGoogle.removeFromSuperview()
            outRemoveAds.removeFromSuperview()
            outRestorePurchases.removeFromSuperview()
            removeInterFrom = 1
        }
        else {
            print("No Value.")
        }

        if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()){
            print("IAP is enabled, loading...")
            let productID:NSSet = NSSet(objects:"IAP id")
            let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        }
        else{
            print("Please enable IAPS")

        }

    }


    //IAP Ads

    @IBAction func removeAds(sender: UIButton) {
        for product in list{
            let prodID = product.productIdentifier
            if (prodID == "IAP id"){
                p = product
                buyProduct()
                break
            }
        }
    }
    @IBAction func restorePurchases(sender: UIButton) {
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }


    //IAP Functions

    var list = [SKProduct]()
    var p = SKProduct()

    func removeAds(){
        banner.removeFromSuperview()
        bannerGoogle.removeFromSuperview()
        outRemoveAds.removeFromSuperview()
        outRestorePurchases.removeFromSuperview()
        let theValue = 10
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(theValue, forKey: "val")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }

    func buyProduct(){
        print("Buy: "+p.productIdentifier)
        let pay = SKPayment (product: p)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay as SKPayment)
    }

    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
        print("Product Request")
        let myProduct = response.products

        for product in myProduct{
            print("Product Added")
            print(product.productIdentifier)
            print(product.localizedTitle)
            print(product.localizedDescription)
            print(product.price)

            list.append(product as SKProduct)
        }
    }

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        print("Add Payment")

        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions{
            let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
            print(trans.error)
            switch trans.transactionState{
            case .Purchased:
                print("IAP unlocked")
                print(p.productIdentifier)

                let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String
                switch prodID{
                case "IAP id":
                    print("Remove Ads")
                    removeAds()
                default:
                    print("IAP not setup")
                }
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break
            case .Failed:
                print ("Buy error")
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break
            default:
                print("default: Error")
                break
            }
        }
    }

    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        print("Purchases Restored")

        _ = []
        for transaction in queue.transactions {
            let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as SKPaymentTransaction

            let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String
            switch prodID{
            case "IAP id":
                print("Remove Ads")
                removeAds()
            default:
                print("IAP not setup")
            }


        }
    }
    func finishTransaction(trans:SKPaymentTransaction){
        print("Finshed Transaction")
    }

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, removedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        print("Remove Transaction")
    }
}
```

Put:

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
```

in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10400514)

Comment: True, let me do that.